# How can I add my implemented code as a preprocessing layer to tensorflow Sequential?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-processing, conv-neural-network

I want to add a custom function as a layer for image processing tasks in TensorFlow Keras Sequential. The custom function will hold my code logic of image processing. But, I couldn't find the solution to it.
I have the following code that performs some image preprocessing tasks but I can't understand how could I make it run in TensorFlow as a layer.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

impth='...//filepath'
img = cv2.imread(impth, 1)
img = cv2.resize(img,(512,512))
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# convert img to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# do adaptive threshold on gray image
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 101, 3)

# apply morphology open then close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
blob = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9,9))
blob = cv2.morphologyEx(blob, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# invert blob
blob = (255 - blob)

# Get contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(blob, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
big_contour = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

# test blob size
blob_area_thresh = 1000
blob_area = cv2.contourArea(big_contour)
if blob_area < blob_area_thresh:
    print("Blob Is Too Small")

result = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(result, [big_contour], -1, (0,0,255), 1)
```

here the result contains my image processed Image.

But, I couldn't add it to the tensorflow as a layer.
I want to add this as a layer in the following code-

```
input_shape = (BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE, CHANNELS)
n_classes = nClassNum
model = models.Sequential([
    resize_and_rescale,
    data_augmentation,
    layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3,),activation = 'relu', input_shape = input_shape),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3,3,),activation = 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3,3,),activation = 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3,),activation = 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3,),activation = 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3,),activation = 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu'),
    layers.Dense(n_classes,activation='softmax'),
])
```

Here is the optional code snippet of the whole code of TensorFlow pipeline and layers-

```
dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "../dataset",
    shuffle = True,
    image_size = (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE
)
train_ds, val_ds, test_ds = get_dataset_partitions_tf(dataset)

train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size = tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size = tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = test_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size = tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

resize_and_rescale = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1.0/255)
])

data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2)
])

input_shape = (BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE, CHANNELS)
n_classes = nClassNum
model = models.Sequential([
    resize_and_rescale,
    data_augmentation,
    layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3,),activation = 'relu', input_shape = input_shape),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3,3,),activation = 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3,3,),activation = 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3,),activation = 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3,),activation = 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3,),activation = 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu'),
    layers.Dense(n_classes,activation='softmax'),
])

model.build(input_shape=input_shape)

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss= tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation in tensorflow for defining custom layers? https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers.

Please go through it if you haven't and then ask if you have any problems.

Comment: Thank you I've already checked it. And I wanted to manipulate the 'tf.Tensor' data that I was getting in 'inputs' parameter of 'call()' function. But I couldn't proceed. I have opened a question about the matter unfortunately, I've got a negative vote for asking the question. I'm trying to figure out the issue by myself. Thank you @tintin98 for your response